# Launching python script every week from itself

Tags: python

I have a python script which I turned into `.exe` with pyinstaller and then packaged it with nsis so anyone may install it without the need to install dependencies. Script parses web page and saves the result into an excel file in it's own directory. Is it possible to run the script from itself every week? I've seen `schedule`, but it doesn't really suit me, since script has to be running all the time while I need it to run only once a week. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it within the application but there's the cmd command schtasks with which you can do it like that.

```
 SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC WEEKLY /D SUN /TN "MyTasks\Notepad task" /TR "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" /ST 11:00
```